# (ARCHITECTURE pcarch OF ENTITY program_counter) : Error : Type mismatch

Tags: vhdl

I found the following code for a simple processor online. I am trying to add some analogue components in VHDL AMS using hAMSter. But it is generating the Error : Type mismatch

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 

entity program_counter is
port (
   clk, en_A, ld, inc, reset: in STD_LOGIC;
   aBus: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
   dBus: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
);
end program_counter;
architecture pcArch of program_counter is
signal pcReg : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
begin
process(clk) begin
   if clk'event and clk = '1' then 
         if reset = '1' then
               pcReg <= x"0000";
         elsif ld = '1' then
               pcReg <= dBus;
         elsif inc = '1' then
       pcReg <= pcReg + x"0001";
         end if;
   end if;
end process;
aBus <= pcReg when en_A = '1' else "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
end pcArch;
```

Specifically on the line:

```
pcReg <= pcReg + x"0001";
```

The error is:

```
(ARCHITECTURE pcarch OF ENTITY program_counter) : Error : Type mismatch
```

Please help with a fix.

Comment: Please use Google to search why you shouldn't use `std_logic_unsigned` and or arithmetic using `std_logic_vector`... This has also been explained on stack overflow many times.

Comment: There is no `ARCHITECTURE pcarch OF ENTITY program_counter` line in the code you show. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the "Asking" section (especially "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example").

Comment: On [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/), VCS and Incisive elaborate the code without any error. Current status doesn't seem sufficient to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue with the std_logic_unsigned library. But even with the new libraries: library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all; The error still occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your up-to-date code + test bench

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The code is now updated. The same error occurs.

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate a digital microcontroller in an AMS simulator?

Comment: I needed to add some analogue components which is why I am now using VHDL AMS in hAMSter.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is too frustrating to see you only do half the work. (Changing library alone will of course not fix it...)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity program_counter is
    port (
        clk, en_A, ld, inc, reset: in STD_LOGIC;
        dBus: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        aBus: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture pcArch of program_counter is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all; 
    signal pcReg : unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then 
            if reset = '1' then
                pcReg <= (others => '0');
            elsif ld = '1' then
                pcReg <= unsigned(dBus);
            elsif inc = '1' then
                pcReg <= pcReg + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    aBus <= std_logic_vector(pcReg) when en_A = '1' else (others => 'z');
end architecture;
```

please: next time do better searching. This is very common/simple code, and examples are available all over the web.

Comment: Which program are you using to build this? The code I posted built fine in Quartus 2 in VHDL. I needed to add some analogue components which is why I am now using VHDL AMS in hAMSter. The error only occurs in hamster and your code has more errors than the one I posted. Error : Simulation object for entity program_counter not created because of 10 errors

Comment: The code I originally posted has Error : Simulation object for entity program_counter not created because of 2 errors both of Error : Type mismatch on the posted line of code.

Comment: I tried a downloaded version of hAMSter, but I'm missing many ieee libraries

Comment: Yes. I added the ieee libraries as the errors cropped up. Yours has Error : Unknown identifier "unsigned" on line pcReg <= unsigned(dBus); and Error : Type mismatch on the same line so on and so forth.

Comment: How did you add the library?? Of these types are missing, you did not include the official IEEE library

Comment: Ok, maybe not the best response, but I recoded the entire project so that it can build in Quartus 2. All simulations are successful. Regards.